# How to analyse unmanged memory of DotNet Process from Dump

Tags: c#, windbg, dump

I've a problem at a customer that our netcore applications grows in memory size to over 11GB. (it will grow larger and crash with out of memory exception)
We now created a procdump before we restarted the process.

I used MemoryAnalyser to find that most of the memory used by our process is unmanged memory.
How can I now analyse the unmanged memory? To find whats allocated and taking so much space.

Comment: Depending on the operating system, you need either WinDbg or LLVM Dbg.

Comment: Yeah, but is there a Tutorial how to analyze unmanged memory?

Comment: There are definitely great books and tutorials if you use search engines.

Comment: I've not found a good Tutorial. I found some, mostly for managed, but not how to analyze unmanged part of managed process.

Comment: The steeper the learning curve, the more difficult it is for you to find valuable materials. Even if you happen to find great tutorials prepared for intermediate/advanced reader, you might feel them terrible for beginners. That's probably why overall asking for tutorials/books are considered off-topic here. Books like "Inside-Windows-Debugging" are the de facto bibles in this field, but again your opinion might differ. Open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com if you have the fund to spare.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043889/how-to-find-what-is-in-unmanaged-memory-in-dump-by-windbg

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425998/what-is-windbg-unknown-memory

Comment: This is too little information to diagnose the issue. How can I analyze the issue? Use a native memory profiler. Look for pinned objects on .NET side. You must know your application at least a little bit. What does it do? Does it deal with Bitmaps? Does it load a unmanaged DLL?

Comment: Are there ny suggestions for a native memory profiler? Didn't really find one. Best would be one wich also supports managed, so I can leave that out.