windbg: eeheap doesn't show all the managed heap in CLR
I am doing research about .NET application memory analysis with windbg, ok?
The program goes as follows:
using System.Formats.Asn1;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DemoDump
{

    public class AllocateManagedMemory {

        // Import the VirtualAlloc function from the Windows API
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

        public void ManagedMemory(uint allocationSize, uint allocationType, uint protectFlags) {
            IntPtr allocatedMemory = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, allocationSize, allocationType, protectFlags);
            if (allocatedMemory == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // VirtualAlloc failed, handle the error
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Console.WriteLine($"VirtualAlloc failed with error code: {errorCode}");
            }
            else
            {
                // VirtualAlloc succeeded, use the allocated memory
                Console.WriteLine("Memory allocated successfully!");
                Console.WriteLine($"Allocated Memory Address: 0x{allocatedMemory.ToInt64():X}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static int[] arr;
        public static AllocateUnmanagedMemory cls;
        public static AllocateManagedMemory clr;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int GBSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / sizeof(int);

            Console.WriteLine("Allocating");

            arr = new int[GBSize];

            const uint heapSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
            clr = new AllocateManagedMemory();
            clr.ManagedMemory(heapSize, 0x1000, 0x04);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


The program above creates an int array with size of 1GB, and is directly using VirtualAlloc win32 API to allocate another 1GB managed heap memory.
So based on the theory,  in the CLR besides the GC(which is the default heap manager of .NET application), there will be another heap manager, right?
Let's verify this point by running: !address -summary command

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                 77     7dfe`4c8da000 ( 125.993 TB)           98.43%
MEM_RESERVE                              90      201`2801f000 (   2.005 TB)  99.89%    1.57%
MEM_COMMIT                              425        0`8b6f7000 (   2.179 GB)   0.11%    0.00%

Yes, the committed memory is roughly 2.17GB, right? Then I dig more by running !address -f:MEM_COMMIT -c:".echo %1 %3 %5 %7", which prints out
0x5f3a0000 0x1000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f3a1000 0x2ab000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f64c000 0xb000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f657000 0x1b000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f672000 0x2000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f674000 0x2d000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x7ffe0000 0x1000 MEM_COMMIT Other
0x4580ca7000 0x5000 MEM_COMMIT Stack
...thousands of lines omitted...

And then I write a script to handle the output line by line, the target is to know what is the memory size for each type in the 2.17GB committed memory. Then the result goes as follows:
Memory by Type:
type: Other 1.8632812MB
type: <unknown> 2175.4531MB
type: Stack 0.359375MB
type: PEB 0.00390625MB
type: TEB 0.09375MB
type: Heap 4.375MB
type: Image 48.816406MB

ok? You can obviously see that the committed unknown is 2175MB.
But when I run command !eeheap and try it find the customized heap manager in CLR, I can not find it.
0:000> !eeheap
Loader Heap:
----------------------------------------
System Domain:        7ff910d29690
LoaderAllocator:      7ff910d29690
LowFrequencyHeap:     7ff8b10b0000(10000:a000) 7ff8b1090000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0ff0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0fc0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0fb0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f80000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f30000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f10000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0ed0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0de0000(60000:60000) 7ff8b0d30000(3000:1000) Size: 0xeb000 (962560) bytes total, 0x2000 (8192) bytes wasted.
HighFrequencyHeap:    7ff8b10d0000(10000:1000) 7ff8b10c0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b10a0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b1080000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0fe0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0fd0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0fa0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f90000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f70000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f60000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f50000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f40000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f20000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0f00000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0ef0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0ee0000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0e40000(10000:10000) 7ff8b0d34000(9000:5000) Size: 0x106000 (1073152) bytes total, 0x4000 (16384) bytes wasted.
StubHeap:             7ff8b0d3d000(3000:1000) Size: 0x1000 (4096) bytes total.
IndirectionCellHeap:  7ff8b0d40000(6000:1000) Size: 0x1000 (4096) bytes total.
LookupHeap:           7ff8b0d4f000(4000:1000) Size: 0x1000 (4096) bytes total.
ResolveHeap:          7ff8b0d84000(57000:1000) Size: 0x1000 (4096) bytes total.
DispatchHeap:         7ff8b0d53000(31000:1000) Size: 0x1000 (4096) bytes total.
CacheEntryHeap:       7ff8b0d46000(9000:1000) Size: 0x1000 (4096) bytes total.
Total size:           Size: 0x1f7000 (2060288) bytes total, 0x6000 (24576) bytes wasted.
----------------------------------------
Domain 1:             020c8b4a5070
LoaderAllocator:      020c8b4a5070
No unique loader heaps found.
----------------------------------------
JIT Manager:          020c8b43d850
LoaderCodeHeap:       7ff8b0e50000(80000:35000) Size: 0x35000 (217088) bytes total.
LoaderCodeHeap:       7ff8b1000000(80000:10000) Size: 0x10000 (65536) bytes total.
Total size:           Size: 0x45000 (282624) bytes total.
----------------------------------------

========================================
Number of GC Heaps: 1
----------------------------------------
generation 0 starts at 20c8cf51030
generation 1 starts at 20c8cf51018
generation 2 starts at 20c8cf51000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
Small object heap
         segment            begin        allocated        committed allocated size          committed size         
    020c8cf50000     020c8cf51000     020c8d119fe8     020c8d122000 0x1c8fe8 (1871848)      0x1d2000 (1908736)     
Large object heap starts at 20c9cf51000
         segment            begin        allocated        committed allocated size          committed size         
    020c9cf50000     020c9cf51000     020c9cfa04f8     020c9cfa1000 0x4f4f8 (324856)        0x51000 (331776)       
    020caf280000     020caf281000     020cef281038     020cef282000 0x40000038 (1073741880) 0x40002000 (1073750016)
Pinned object heap starts at 20ca4f51000
         segment            begin        allocated        committed allocated size          committed size         
    020ca4f50000     020ca4f51000     020ca4f5ac28     020ca4f62000 0x9c28 (39976)          0x12000 (73728)        
------------------------------
GC Allocated Heap Size:    Size: 0x40222140 (1075978560) bytes.
GC Committed Heap Size:    Size: 0x40237000 (1076064256) bytes.

Total bytes consumed by CLR: 0x40473000 (1078407168)

Based on the design of eeheap. When I didn't pass any parameters to it, it will output all the heap manager in CLR, right? But how so

I fail to understand why eeheap should report the size of the allocation resulting from VirtualAlloc. This allocation will be part of the process' working set, but there's no reason it should be part of the managed heap since it's not, by definition, managed. Or did I misunderstand your question?

@Neitsa Memory that is reported as  by WinDbg is memory that was allocated via VirtualAlloc(). And  is managed heap, right? refer
to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425998/what-is-windbg-unknown-memory/39428167#39428167

VirtualAlloc() does not use any heap manager. It gets the memory directly from the kernel. As mentioned in the accepted answer you linked: <unknown> is a combination of a) .NET GC heap, b) calls to VirtualAlloc(), c) calls to HeapAlloc() with sizes >512k, and much more
